# Is this correct use of pattern matching and active patterns?

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# and functional and am working on some HTML parsing code. I want to remove from a HTML document elements that match some criteria. Here I have a sequence of objects (HtmlNodes) and want to remove them from the document.

Is this idiomatic way of using pattern matching? Also as HtmlNode.Remove() has a side-effect on the original HtmlDocument object, is there any particular way of structuring the code to make the side-effect obvious or how should this be handled. You can be as pedantic as you like with the code.

```
open HtmlAgilityPack

let removeNodes (node : HtmlNode) = 

    let (|HiddenNodeCount|) (n : HtmlNode) =
        match n.SelectNodes("*[@style[contains(.,'visibility:hidden')]]") with
        | null -> 0
        | _ as x -> Seq.length x

    match node with
        | x when x.Name.ToLower() = "script" -> node.Remove() 
        | x when x.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Comment -> node.Remove()
        | HiddenNodeCount x when x > 0 -> node.Remove()
        | _ -> ()

let html = "some long messy html code would be here"
let dom = new HtmlDocument(OptionAutoCloseOnEnd=true)
dom.LoadHtml(html)

let nodes = dom.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
nodes |> Seq.toArray |> Array.iter removeNodes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I prefer `if elif else` over pattern matching when you don't have a data structure to decompose (it's just less typing, and may also serve to differentiate between when a structure is being decomposed versus simpler case testing).

There are some odd things in your code. The Active Pattern isn't very helpful here for two reasons: first, its scope is limited to removeNodes so it is only used once. I'll address the second issues later, but first I will show how I would write this by eliminating the Active Pattern and, for me at least, making the side-effects more obvious (by separating the code which tests whether a node should be removed from the code that does the removing):

```
let shouldRemoveNode (node : HtmlNode) = 
    if node.Name.ToLower() = "script" then true
    elif node.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Comment then true
    else match node.SelectNodes("*[@style[contains(.,'visibility:hidden')]]") with
         | null -> false
         | x -> Seq.length x > 0

let removeNode (node: HtmlNode) = 
    if shouldRemoveNode(node) then node.Remove() else ()
```

Notice I do use a pattern match in the visibility hidden query since I do get to match against null and bind to x otherwise (rather than binding to x, and then testing x with `if else`).

The second odd thing with your Active Pattern is that you are using it for converting a node to an int, but the length you obtain isn't immediately useful (you still need to perform a test against it). Whereas the more powerful use of an Active Pattern here would be to carve up nodes into different kinds (assuming this isn't ad-hoc, which was may first point). So you could have:

```
//expand to encompass several other kinds of nodes
let (|Script|Comment|Hidden|Other|) (node : HtmlNode) = 
    if node.Name.ToLower() = "script" then Script
    elif node.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Comment then Comment
    else match node.SelectNodes("*[@style[contains(.,'visibility:hidden')]]") with
         | null -> Other
         | x -> if Seq.length x > 0 then Hidden
                else Other

let removeNode (node: HtmlNode) = 
    match node with
    | Script | Comment | Hidden -> node.Remove()
    | Other -> ()
```

**Edit:**

@Pascal made the observation in the comments that `shouldRemoveNode` can be further condensed into one big boolean expression:

```
let shouldRemoveNode (node : HtmlNode) = 
    node.Name.ToLower() = "script" || 
    node.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Comment ||
    match node.SelectNodes("*[@style[contains(.,'visibility:hidden')]]") with
    | null -> false
    | x -> Seq.length x > 0
```

Comment: +1 in this particular case, the `if cond then true elif ...` pattern can be further transformed into `cond ||`. The result is at least as readable (to me).

Comment: nice idea, I added it to the end as an edit (leaving my original shouldRemoveNode implementation the same so that it lines up with the Active Pattern example).

Comment: That was a very helpful answer all round, thanks. The active pattern and how the code is seperated for the side-effects is much better.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me that this is any better than using functions and if-then-else, e.g.

```
let HiddenNodeCount (n : HtmlNode) = 
    match n.SelectNodes("*[@style[contains(.,'visibility:hidden')]]") with 
    | null -> 0 
    | x -> Seq.length x 

if node.Name.ToLower() = "script" then 
    node.Remove()  
elif node.NodeType = HtmlNodeType.Comment then
    node.Remove()  
elif HiddenNodeCount node > 0 then 
    node.Remove()
```

Comment: OK, do you know a good example of when pattern matching would be better than if/else ?

Comment: The canonical case would be matching against structured data (discriminated union, list/array/tuple, etc.) where pattern-matching is much more succinct than anything else.  Apart from that, I don't personally have a strong opinion.  You original code is not bad, it just feels a little `match`-gratuitous to me.